# Need help with functional dependencies (Database Theory)

Tags: database-theory, databases

I'm trying to understand functional dependencies in databases.

Let's say, there are 3 tuples in an instance of a certain relation S as shown below.

[image]

I'm trying to determine if a certain functional dependency will hold over S. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

1) A -> B should hold because no 2 similar value of a give 2 different values in B.

2) B -> A should not hold because 3 -> 1 and then 3-> 5.

3) BC -> A should not hold because (3,3) -> 1 and (3,3) -> 5.

4) BC -> D should hold because (3,3) -> 1 and the second (3,3) -> 1 also.

I'm not sure if I understood it right.